# Forwarding Parameter References to Functions in Rust

Tags: reference, rust

I'm having trouble figuring out what's happening when I forward a reference argument to another function in Rust that also expects a reference argument.

Basically, I'm confused about when a value is a reference (that needs to be de-referenced with `*`) and when it's just a value that can be used directly. For example,

```
fn second(s: &String) {
    println!("Got string '{}'", *s);  // Can also use s 
}

fn first(s: &String) {
    second(s);                        // Can also use &s
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hello, World!");
    first(&s);
}
```

As shown above, any of the four total combinations of passing `s` from `first` into `second` and printing `s` inside `second` works. My intuition says that `s` inside `first` is a reference and thus `&s` would be a double reference, and that `s` inside `second` is a reference that needs to be de-referenced, but it doesn't seem to actually matter. What's going on here?

Comment: You've actually asked two separate questions; I've linked to appropriate duplicates.

Comment: TL;DR: `println!` automatically takes a reference, and `Deref` coercions convert `&&String` to a `&String` for you.

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String) or Vec (&Vec) as a function argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the help!